# The while loop double prints first before entering a value

Tags: java, stack

The String asd prints double before asking the input for switcher, I feel hopeless now. I want the string "asd"to only print once but in my case in prints twice, my guess would be an error or looping, sorry I'm very new here and into programming

```
public class FruitBasket {

static String option;
static String choice1;
static int catcher;
static int counter1 = 1;
static int counter = 0;
static String eater = "e";
static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);       
static Stack<String> basket = new Stack();
static String switcher;

public static void main(String[] args) {

    catching();

}

static void catching(){

    System.out.println("Catch and eat any of these fruits: " + "'apple', 'orange', 'mango', 'guava'" );
    System.out.println("A apple, O orange, M mango, G guava");
    System.out.print("How many fruits would you like to catch? ");
    catcher = sc.nextInt();

    switches();
     }

     static void switches(){

    while(counter1 < catcher)  {
    String asd = "Fruit " + counter1 + " of " + catcher + ":";
    System.out.print(asd);

    switcher = sc.nextLine();
         switch (switcher) {
            case "a":
                basket.push("apple");
                counter++;
                counter1++;
                break;
```

Comment: You aren't showing us how you initialize counter and catcher, I tried with catcher = 4 and counter = 0 and the string asd doesn't print twice.

Comment: pardon I'm so noob.
the int counter is just "static int counter;"
for the  catcher would be
 "System.out.print("How many fruits would you like to catch? ");
        catcher = sc.nextInt();""

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: Java and JavaScript are completely unrelated languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you are using sc.nextInt() to get input from the user and it doesn't consume the line so when you use switcher = sc.nextLine(); it still reads the number that the user entered before.

You can add this after catcher = sc.nextInt(); to consume the line:

```
    if (sc.hasNextLine()){
        sc.nextLine();
    }
```

Or alternatively you could use:

```
catcher = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());
```

To convert the user input to an integer value and it will also work.

Comment: This code saved me, thank you very much sir!